# How to change save from button to automatic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

How to make the selected scene automatically saved in Unity? E.g. I would like the 3rd, 6th and 9th scene to be saved automatically. How do I do this? This is my code which works only on the button unfortunately:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 
 public class Scene_Manager : MonoBehaviour
 {
     int Saved_scene;
     int Scene_index;
 
     public void new_game()
     {
         SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
     }
 
     public void Load_Saved_Scene()
     {
         Saved_scene = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Saved");
 
         if(Saved_scene != 0)
             SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(Saved_scene);
         else
             return;
     }
 
     public void Save_and_Exit()
     {
         Scene_index = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Saved", Scene_index);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();
         SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(0);
     }
         
     public void Next_Scene()
     {
         Scene_index = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;
         SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(Scene_index);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you call `Load_Saved_Scene` method.

If you are calling correctly `Load_Saved_Scene` and `Save_and_Exit` method,

I think there is no problem in your code.

Can I see more codes? (Where you are calling those methods)

If you are not calling those methods except button onClick,

You may call `Load_Saved_Scene` methods when 3rd, 6th, 9th scene are finished.

You should call save method at `OnDestroy()` on scene manager code in 3rd, 6th, 9th scene like below.

```
Scene_index = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Saved", Scene_index);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

And when your game opened, check the last saved scene like your `Load_Saved_Scene` does.